# didbegincontact not called spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

My code is like so

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var player: SKSpriteNode!
    var player2: SKSpriteNode!
    var initialplayerposition : CGPoint!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx:0, dy:0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    addplayer()
    addRow(type: .threeS)
}    
func addRandomRow () {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    switch randomNumber {
    case 0 :
        addRow(type: RowType(rawValue:0)!)
        break
    case 1:
        addRow (type: RowType(rawValue: 1)!)
    case 2 :
        addRow(type: RowType(rawValue:2)!)
        break
    case 3 :
        addRow(type: RowType(rawValue:3)!)
        break
    case 4 :
        addRow(type: RowType(rawValue:4)!)
        break
    case 5 :
        addRow(type: RowType(rawValue:5)!)
        break
    default:
        break

    }
}
var lastTimeIntervall = TimeInterval ()
var lastTimeYield = TimeInterval()

func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate (timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval){
    lastTimeYield += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if (lastTimeYield > 0.6){
        lastTimeYield = 0
        addRandomRow()
    }
}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    var timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastTimeIntervall
    lastTimeIntervall = currentTime
    if timeSinceLastUpdate > 1 {
        timeSinceLastUpdate = 1 / 60
        lastTimeIntervall = currentTime

    }
    updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate (timeSinceLastUpdate: timeSinceLastUpdate)
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}

 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Player" {
        print("gameover")
    }
}}
```

and here is my elements created in another file

```
func addplayer()  {
    player = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size:CGSize(width:50, height:50))
    player.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width / 2 , y: 350)
    player.name = "PLAYER"
    player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(CollisionBitMask.Player)
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask =  0
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(CollisionBitMask.Obstacle)
```

and here is the obstacle code

```
   func addObstacle(type:ObstacleType) ->  SKSpriteNode {

    let Obstacle = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width:0, height:30))
    Obstacle.name = "OBSTACLE"
    Obstacle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    switch type {
    case .Small:
        Obstacle.size.width = self.size.width * 0.2
        break
    case.Medium:
        Obstacle.size.width = self.size.width * 0.35
        break
    case .Large:
        Obstacle.size.width = self.size.width * 0.75
        break
    }

    Obstacle.position = CGPoint(x:0, y : self.size.height + Obstacle.size.height)
    Obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: Obstacle.size)
    Obstacle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(CollisionBitMask.Obstacle)
    Obstacle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


    return Obstacle}
```

Comment: You haven't setup your physicsBodies bitmasks

Comment: @Nik i have struct CollisionBitMask {
    static let Player:UInt = 0*00
    static let Obstacle:UInt = 0*01
    
} but it doesnt work either

Comment: Instead of 0*01 and 0*00, try 0b10 and 0b1 (I don't use zero because that's for something that isn't part of collisions/contacts. Also, at least one of the physicsBodies has to be dynamic for the collision/contact to work. Another issue is that you need both nodes to have physicsBodies and both should have the bitmasks to be setup

Comment: the Obstacle (the second element) is already Dynamic but using 0b1 doesnt solve the problem

Comment: I didn't mention yet that in your didBeginContact, you're assuming that bodyA is always going to be player if you want the game to end. You can't assume that unless you sort them in order of categoryBitmasks (because you know which node should have a certain bitmask)

Comment: im already sorting them too but nothing happens, its a little bit confusing here, yes ill edit my post

Comment: You have to set isDynamic for the obstacle after you've created its physicsBody. You also haven't setup the obstacles contactTestBitMask to the category of the player

Comment: none of them works , isDynamic is already set now after creating the physicsBody , and the contactTestBitMask too , its already set to the player , ive tried to set it to the obstacle too but doesnt work

Comment: You're using two different names.  The player name is PLAYER, but you're checking if it's name is Player in didBeginContact. Those two names should be identical

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136080/discussion-on-question-by-gmasa-didbegincontact-not-called-spritekit).

Comment: @BhargavRao I don't think the OP had enough Rep to chat

Comment: @Nik, I've provided them access to write in that particular chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a stupid error from me , the didBegin Function should be like this in swift3

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "PLAYER"){
        print("gameover")
      }
}
```